# Generate a random chain with cauchy distribution using C language

Tags: cauchy-sequences, simulation

Here is my question:

I want to simulate a random variable using cauchy distribution with C language.
Scale and position must be setted manually.

I fuond the GSL library wich contain the function:
gsl_ran_cauchy (const gsl_rng * r, double a)

the problem that i can't unsterstand how to fix the position and the scale and there is not a lot of documentation about that.

Regards

Comment: Welcome on Math.SE! Although this is also math question you might get more help on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0):

As demontstrated in [the examples page of the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Distribution-Examples.html#Random-Number-Distribution-Examples), in order to use the function `gsl_ran_cauchy (const gsl_rng * r, double a)` you must first initialise the random number generation, like this (for example)

```
const gsl_rng_type * T;
gsl_rng * r;

gsl_rng_env_setup();

T = gsl_rng_default;
r = gsl_rng_alloc (T);
```

and then, as you can see in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Cauchy-Distribution.html#The-Cauchy-Distribution) you can simply generate a random cauchy variable with scale `a` by calling the function like this:

```
gsl_ran_cauchy (const gsl_rng * r, double a)
```

I don't understand what you mean by "position". If you simply mean the mean, or equivalently the starting point of your random walk, you can simply say

```
my_ran = mean + gsl_ran_cauchy (const gsl_rng * r, double a)
```